# Time stored in DB minus 2 weeks

Tags: php, mysql, date

I would like to show the date 2 weeks before the date stored in a DB

The date isnt stored in Timestamp, it is stored like 01/01/2015

I have tried the below but this isnt working, can anyone help?

```
echo date('$valid_to', strtotime("-2 week"));
```

Comment: First parameter of date is the format string, not your date. strtotime is the function that could interpret your date string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what code would work instead of mine?

Comment: Another important tip would be to use some unambiguous time format. Think about this date "01/02/03". The system is unable to know what is day, month or year here. You can use either ISO format "yyyy-mm-dd" or a unix timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, however i still need to know where the DB reference goes?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `DateTime` class instead.

```
// timezone is optional
$date = new DateTime($valid_to, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Vilnius'));
echo $date->modify('-2 weeks'); 
// there you have your wanted date
$valid_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Then would recommend `STR_TO_DATE` mysql function to convert to correct timestamp.

For example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE time_col <= STR_TO_DATE('" . $valid_date . "', '%Y-%m-%d')";
```

Comment: This answer is missing the reference time from the Database!

Comment: Thanks, where do i put my variable $valid_to so I can get the correct date?